# How to specify limit and offset in array in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, limit, offset

I have 3 tables `PostText`, `PostImage` and `PostVideo`.
Now I am combining data from all the above three table into a single array called `userposts`.

Now from `userposts` I want to access only 10 records starting with offset 15.

How can I do that?

I tried out `userposts.first(10)`. It gives me first 10 records but I want 10 records starting from offset-15.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Eg: If `arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`, then this `arr[0..2]` would give `[1,2,3]`, `arr[3..5]` would give `[4,5,6]`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should use [`ary[start, length] → new_ary or nil`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) method.

> ..returns a subarray starting at the *start* index and continuing for *length* elements,

```
userposts[10, 15]
```

Comment: Looks like he's using a query though, if he is then `userposts.offset(15).limit(10)` would be better

Comment: @japed You are right.. But from _..from all the above three table into a single **array** called userposts._ I can infer what I answered.. :)

Comment: @japed it gives me an error that undefined method 'offset' for an Array.

Answer (score 25):

`userposts.drop(15).first(10)` will help you

Comment: This works on a normal array, not just ActiveRecord relation arrays. :+1:

Comment: this also works on lazy arrays.